# Integer surgeries along links yielding lens spaces

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory, 3-manifolds, 4-manifolds, surgery-theory

> Does there exist an integer $N$ such that any lens space $L(p,q)$ can be obtained by integer surgery from $S^3$ along a link $L$ with at most $N$ components?

EDIT:
I have worked out the comment by Ian Agol.

Fintushel and Stern have proved the following:
If $K_1$ is a knot in the lens space $L(p,q)$ such that $n_1$-surgery along $K_1$ yields a homology $3$-sphere, then we can represent $K_1$ in the exterior of an unknot $K_0$ in $S^3$ with surgery coefficient $-p/q$. By comparing the ranks of the first homologies we see that $\pm1=pn_1+q\operatorname{lk}_{01}^2$, where $\operatorname{lk}_{01}$ denotes the linking number of $K_0$ and $K_1$ in $S^3$. 
It follows that $L(p,q)$ is homeomorphic to $L(p,\operatorname{lk}_{01}^2)$ and in particular an integer $N$ as in the question has to be larger than $1$.

As suggested by Ian Agol this approach does not give an obstruction for links:
Let $K_1\cup K_2$ be a $2$-component link in $L(p,q)$ such that $(n_1,n_2)$-surgery yields a homology $3$-sphere. As above we can compare the ranks of the first homologies and get
$$\pm1=p(n_1n_2+\operatorname{lk}_{12}^2)+q(n_1\operatorname{lk}_{02}^2+n_2\operatorname{lk}_{01}^2-2\operatorname{lk}_{01}\operatorname{lk}_{02}\operatorname{lk}_{12})$$
which seems to have a solution for any $(p,q)$ coprime.

Comment: I don't know of any restrictions. Josh Greene has classified the lens spaces obtained by surgery on a non-trivial knot (which must be integral). Proposition 1 of Fintushel-Stern gives a simpler homological necessary condition: $\pm q$ is a quadratic residue $(mod p)$. But I suspect that one won't get a simple condition like this for surgeries on links. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01161380

Comment: You might try using results of Berge and Gabai to see what lens spaces you can get. They classify surgeries on knots in the solid torus that give back the solid torus. https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=991095https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1093862

A braid has many embeddings into $S^3$ by doing full twists. Maybe one can find examples of lens spaces obtained by integral Dehn surgery on these links? But one would have to compute the framings to see which ones are integral.

Comment: There are a number of examples for which $N = 2$ suffices: all lens spaces that are rational surgeries on torus knots (since the surgery coefficient is integer±1/n; these were classified by Moser) and all lens spaces that bound rational homology balls (classified by Lisca; this is because each of them bounds a rational homology ball built with one 1-handle and one 2-handle; this was shown partly by Lisca, and partly by Baker, Buck, and Lecuona).

Comment: Actually I think that one can show $N = 2$ cannot work for all lens spaces, but not in a very nice way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the comments. But it would be great if you could give me a few more hints.
@Ian Agol: As far as I can tell the Berge and Gabai papers are only about knots. I am not sure how this can yield a link with a possibly new integer lens space surgery.

Or do you suggest classifying surgeries on links in the solid torus that give back the solid torus and then checking which of those surgeries are integer and which lens spaces one gets?

Comment: @Marco Golla: I understand your comment on the examples where $N=2$ suffices. But I do not see how to conclude that $N=2$ cannot work in general.

Comment: @MarcKegel: the second comment was not meant to follow from the first. To clarify, I think that one can play around with some specific (families of) examples and obstruct them from being an integral surgery on a 2-component link. Sorry for the mix-up.

Comment: @MarcKegel Yes, I meant the second thing you said. But this probably won’t get much more than what Marco suggests.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Building on Ian's comment: another way to construct lens spaces for which $N=2$ works is to cable the Hopf link with Berge–Gabai patterns. For the right surgery coefficients (i.e. the ones that give solid tori back), after surgery you're just gluing together two solid tori, so you certainly get a lens space, but you need to check the slopes you obtain.